# How To Obtain/Guesstimate Filesize Of Individual Elements On A Webpage

Tags: jquery

Long time lurker of StackOverflow, but I believe this is my first question. Certainly the first on this account.

I'm looking to create a tool which needs some functionality which I haven't been able to find yet. Basically, I'd like to be able to use jQuery to estimate the size of any given element of a webpage (whether that be `<div>` or `<img>` or any other) in terms of bytes rather than dimension. All Googling on the subject gives me helpful answers about dimension, but nothing about 'weight'.

I'm sure there's a simple answer, but I haven't been able to find it. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry, but a div's size in bytes doesn't make much sense. Do you mean the HTML markup's size? Or the size of an image generated from the element's screen representation? If the latter, which file format? Could you give an example of a div and its byte size?

Comment: Size, as in bytes contained in the string inside something like a `<div>` and filesize of external resources ?

Comment: I mean the amount of bytes which would be sent down the phone line to transfer just that element from the server to the client, rather than the whole page.

Comment: Since you can't download a single element, only a single file, I'm not sure why this information would even be useful.

Comment: That's really subjective, depending on how you're constructing the div, what business logic may be dependent on rendering that.  A little more clarity would be beneficial.  What would the benefit of this (potential) tool be over simply viewing the network profiler while the page loads?  Is this only to measure the size in bytes of the string for the HTML?  Very unclear right now.

Comment: I thought this would be simple, especially given the 'guesstimate' in the title. @adeneo is closest to what I mean. Is it possible?

Comment: More clarity. A 56k modem takes longer to download a webpage, including the markup itself and any external resources, than a cable modem. I'm assuming that's because of the difference in the amount of bytes per second each modem can receive. I'd like to know how to work out how many bytes the modem would receive. Surely that is finite and also static? More importantly I'd like to work out the 'heaviest' elements of any given page, for reasons that aren't important. Hence needing to split it down further.